# Touchpad left-click and single tap not working

Tags: touchpad

I recently bought an Asus K54L and immediately installed Ubuntu 11.10 along side of Windows 7. The touchpad was working in both Windows and Ubuntu, but after restarting a couple of times (after updates and installations, etc.) and all of a sudden the touchpad was stuck in the left-click mode. I checked and it's now happening in Windows, too. The only updates I was able to do before this happened were `apt-get update`. I decided to upgrade to 12.04 to see if that would fix it, but no such luck.

I've read a ton of stuff out there about this out there, but I can't seem to find anyone who is having the same problem. Perhaps it's just the hardware? I've never had a problem with this before, and I don't really know how to troubleshoot. Please help

**Edit:** I restarted Ubuntu last night in recovery mode and ran some clean up script available from the list of options there. When I continued on through the booting process, I found that the mouse worked in this "recovery mode." When I restarted again, it was broken again. I didn't try it in Windows. Do they share the same configuration file or something? I would assume not.

Also, I found [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics#Advanced_Configuration) but it's for arch linux, and I'm not sure if it applies to Ubuntu. How should I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being a hardware problem. Unfortunately the only fix is replacing the motherboard

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I would try shutting down and pulling the battery out for a few seconds and put it back in and start it up. 
EDIT:

It looks like its a bug that is ASUS specific :( > [Elantech Touchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/931818)